# Under what circumstances does TAM charge their $75 rebooking fee?

Tags: air-travel, fees-and-charges, tam-airlines

I'm looking at a flight on the TAM (Brazil) website. It's a decent price, but it lists "Rebooking" at $75 more. Does that mean that if weather or their screw-up or something else interferes with the flight that they will take $75 more to put me on a different flight?

Comment: This should be laid out in their Conditions of Carriage, an English version of which is available [on the LATAM website](http://www.lan.com/en_us/sitio_personas/conditions-to-the-contract-of-transportation/).

Comment: No mention of such a fee there, but at the bottom was a link to "optional and additional fees" which also did not list such a fee, but it did have a fee with a name that sounded similar.  The amount of that one was $35.  Then I thought I would go through the booking process but stop short of payment to see whether I could get more details.   The flight search results had a completely different layout and the price had more than doubled!

Answer (score 2):

Rebooking fees are usually only for changes you request them to do, not for involuntary changes caused by delays, weather, mechanical issues, etc.

Comment: Hmmm.  Well, I can't risk $75 on a "usually."  Star Peru offers a lower price, but the Visa Verification has crashed three times already.  Matrix says LAN has a great price, but I know they'll add a huge non-resident fee to that.

Comment: @WGroleau the fee only applies for voluntary rebooking (at your own request). IIRC, LAN does not apply non-resident "fees" inside Chile, instead it price-discriminates on point of sale. However to be sure of this check the "Sales Restrictions" category in the fare rules, which can be seen on the Matrix on the final page.

Comment: Yes, the "rules" say sold only in Peru to Peruvian residents (as I expected).  If I change the sales city from default to Dallas, $258 is added.  The difference is odd, considering LAN and TAM are really the same company.  Matrix doesn't even show TAM, but that's probably because the TAM website said that LAN was operating the flight.

Comment: Hmmm.  Went to TAM again, same search.  This time, it's in Portuguese, and what was "rebooking" does translate to "changes by you" and is US$50 instead of 75.  But the fare is now in reales, and converts to the higher price.